# jQuery: how to do an after click event in jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I have a tic tac toe game, where my board is a `<table>` and the `<td>`s are the cells. Every time I click on a td, it appends an x img or an o img.

This is my jQuery code - note: check var, if there are already five or more clicks on the board, then it will start to check if someone already wins the game.

```
 var player = 1;
 var check = 0;

 $("td").bind("click", function(){
            if(player==1){
                $('<img src="x.png" alt="x" name="x"/>').appendTo(this);
                player=player+1;
                check+=1;
            } else {
                $('<img src="o.jpg" alt="o" name="o"/>').appendTo(this);
                player=player-1;
                check+=1;
            }
        });
```

my html table is this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td id="one"></td>
         <td id="two"></td>
         <td id="three"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td id="four"></td>
        <td id="five"></td>
        <td id="six"></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="seven"></td>
         <td id="eight"></td>
         <td id="nine"></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

my problem is I do not know what to do with my winning condition code(for brevity sake, I just posted here the condition that when cell one two three have the x marks, player one wins), for now I made a mouseup function:

```
$("td").mouseup(function(){     
            var one = $("#one").children("img").attr("name");
            var two = $("#two").children("img").attr("name");
            var three = $("#three").children("img").attr("name");

        if(check=>5){
                if(one=="x"&&two=="x"&&three=="x"){
                        alert("player one wins");   
                }
        }

});
```

Initially, I put this code after the check+=1 lines, but I immediately found out that there is a one click delay, the same thing is also happening with my current code. I discovered that in both cases when you click a td it do two things at once: it checks if there is already a winning combination (but bec. the image is not yet inserted then it will do nothing) and it inserts the img.

What I think I need is an after click function that is every time immediately after an image is inserted it will check if there is already a winning combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it at the end of the click handler

```
var player = 1;
var check = 0;

$("td").bind("click", function () {
    if (player == 1) {
        $('<img src="x.png" alt="x" name="x"/>').appendTo(this);
        player = player + 1;
        check += 1;
    } else {
        $('<img src="o.jpg" alt="o" name="o"/>').appendTo(this);
        player = player - 1;
        check += 1;
    }

    //just add it after here
    var one = $("#one").children("img").attr("name");
    var two = $("#two").children("img").attr("name");
    var three = $("#three").children("img").attr("name");

    if (check >= 5) {
        if (one == "x" && two == "x" && three == "x") {
            alert("player one wins");
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mKvr2/)

---

The problem is, click event is fired after mouseup event is triggered so in the mouseup handler you will always get the value of `check` wrong

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mKvr2/1/)